# Diana Rigg who played Olenna Tyrell on Game of Thrones has passed away at the age of 82

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Diana Rigg who played Olenna Tyrell on Game of Thrones [has passed away at the age of 82](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2020-09-11/diana-rigg-game-of-thrones-james-bond-star-dies-olenna-tyrell/12652792)

[image]

She was also known for her role as Contessa Teresa di Vicenzo in James Bond 007's *On Her Majesty's Secret Service*, and a myriad others on stage and screen.

She was most notably known in the SFF community for her role as Olenna Tyrell and her excellent portrayal of the strong matriarch of House Tyrell.

RIP Queen

Comment: "Most known for!?"  _Emma Peel!_

Answer (score 22):

Actually, Diana Rigg's best know role among genre fans was, **by far**, Emma Peel from *The Avengers*.

[image: Emma Peel]

She also had a wonderful turn in *The Great Muppet Caper*.

[image: Miss Piggy and Lady Holiday]

Comment: I believe the full title was *ABC's Avengers Assemble*.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite No way. The  Avengers is the correct title. It predates the marvel version and dates from the 1960s. It was produced by ABC though

Comment: @mmmmm Marvel’s Avengers date from the 1960s too, admittedly two years after the ABC TV show debuted (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avengers_(comic_book))

Comment: Indeed, sir. Props for noting the role that really made her famous.

Answer (score 7):

For the younger SFF fans out there, let it not be forgotten that Dame Rigg also had a memorable appearance as Mrs. Gillyflower in the modern *Doctor Who* episode "The Crimson Horror" alongside her daughter, Rachael Stirling. The episode is a delight to watch and a true testament to both mother and daughter's acting abilities.

[image]

Comment: They also played together in *Detectorists*, which isn't genre (aside some possibly-hyper-intelligent magpies), but is well worth a watch if you like gentle low-key British sort-of-comedy. Modern Doctor Who fans may also recognise Toby Jones (the Dream Lord from *Amy's Choice*).